# Modifying Bootstrap's "active" class

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a little problem with my navbar written in Bootstrap. Everything works properly but I would like to modify .active class given to < li> elements of my navbar by Bootstrap. I wrote my own .active class, but for some reason browser doesn't see it. Links in html file look like this:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Is there any way to do this without interference in bootstrap.css?

edit:
Class I've written looks like this:

```
.active{
 a{
   background-color: $transparent;
   text-decoration: overline;
   text-decoration-color: $color1;
  }
}
```

Ok, as ussual the problem was me being stupid. I forgot to transfer my edited .scss file to .css :\

Comment: provide us with the actual class you've written, make sure you are referencing the pseudo class properly.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this**
**css**

```
active.yourclassname {
   //here your css properties

}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li class="active yourclassname"><a href="#">hello</a></li>
</ul>
```